# How to translate between custom choice type and widget items?

Tags: defcustom, widget

I have a custom variable

```
(defcustom myvar ....
  :type '(choice (const :tag "foo" 1) ...))
```

and I need to map it to

```
(widget-create ...
               '(item :tag "foo" :value 1)
               ...)
```

Obviously I can write something like

```
(mapcar (lambda (item)
          `(item :tag ,(third item) :value ,(fourth item)))
        (rest (custom-variable-type 'myvar)))
```

but I was wondering if there is something more "official".

Comment: No, there's nothing provided for this, AFAIK.